# Unexpected value 'DecoratorFactory' declared by the module 'ComponentsModule'

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, module, components

I have already found an item that addresses my problem but I feel like I am following the recommendations and the problem persists.

I'm trying to use a component on several pages

I really don't understand what's wrong with my code.

components.module.ts

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {PrincipalHeaderComponent} from './principal-header/principal-header.component';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [ PrincipalHeaderComponent, NgModule ],
    exports: [ PrincipalHeaderComponent ]
})
export class ComponentsModule {}
```

home.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { HomePage } from './home.page';
import {AppointmentComponent} from '../../components/views/appointment/appointment.component';
import {ComponentsModule} from '../../components/components.module';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomePage
  }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule,
        IonicModule,
        ComponentsModule,
        RouterModule.forChild(routes)
    ],
    declarations: [HomePage, AppointmentComponent]
})
export class HomePageModule {}
```

planning.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { PlanningPage } from './planning.page';
import {ComponentsModule} from '../../components/components.module';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: PlanningPage
  }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule,
        IonicModule,
        ComponentsModule,
        RouterModule.forChild(routes),
    ],
  declarations: [PlanningPage]
})
export class PlanningPageModule {}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok I resolved it with deletion of NgModule in declaration of my components.module.ts